# O que são métricas orientadas à função?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software

Lendo um pouco sobre Engenharia de Software, em um dos parágrafos, cita um pouco sobre métricas orientadas a função ou funcionalidades, mas nada aprofundado. Tem até uma pergunta nessa prova de [Analista/Programador de Sistemas<sup>q22</sup>](https://arquivo.pciconcursos.com.br/provas/24896692/0a600d3cf7f0/analista_prog_sistema.pdf) que referencia isso.

O que são métricas orientadas à função?

Comment: mais conhecido como "Pontos de Função"

Answer (score 1):

É uma **métrica de software**:

Métricas de softwares possibilitam realizar uma das atividades mais fundamentais do processo de gerenciamento de projetos: o planejamento. A partir desse, pode-se identificar a quantidade de esforço, de custo e das atividades que serão necessárias para a realização do projeto.

Em vez de contar as linhas de código, a métrica orientada à função concentra-se na **funcionalidade do software**. Em 1979, Allan Albrecht, introduziu uma técnica de avaliação conhecida como Ponto de Função(Métrica orientada a função).

- Baseada na visão de negócio do usuário;
- É independente da linguagem utilizada e de qualquer tecnologia em geral;
- Ela não permite calcular o esforço de desenvolvimento, mas gera uma variável
- que pode permitir seu cálculo;
- Auxilia o usuário final a melhorar o exame e avaliação de projetos.

**Seus objetivos são**:

- Medir o que foi requisitado e recebido pelo usuário;
- Prover uma métrica de medição para apoiar a análise de produtividade e qualidade;
- Prover uma forma de estimar o tamanho do software;
- Prover um fator de normalização para comparação de software.

existem algumas outras métricas que são:

- **Métricas Orientadas ao Tamanho**
- **Medidas Diretas**

  - Custo, Esforço, Linhas de Código, Velocidade de Execução, Memória, Número de Erros e Complexidade ciclomática
- **Medidas Indiretas**

  - Funcionalidade, Qualidade, Complexidade, Eficiência, Confiabilidade e Manutenibilidade

Respondendo a questão da prova. LOC = Lines Of Code, PF = Pontos de Função

Letra D

[FONTE](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9trica_de_software)

Comment: [No gabarito diz que a resposta é D](https://arquivo.pciconcursos.com.br/provas/24896692/7938278e68d0/gab_definitivo.pdf). PS.: Só pra constar, não foi eu quem negativou.

Comment: é, na real, faz sentido. vou editar =]